# The empty set possesses every property.

Tags: set-theory

*THEOREM: $X$ is arbitrary set. Let $E$ be a property. Then $x\in \emptyset_X\implies E(x).$*

*PROOF: $(x\in \emptyset_X\implies E(x))=\lnot(x\in\emptyset_X)\lor E(x).$

The negation $\lnot(x\in\emptyset_X)$ is true for any $x\in X$.*

After this theorem in my textbook there is written that it means the empty set possesses any property.

I want to know what does it mean precisely. Can I do a next thing? I have a set function $f$ on a collection of all subsets of $X$. I dont know anything about this function. But I can say $f(\emptyset)=0$. Why? Because the empty set possesses every property. Is it correct? (I know it is not) But why it is not correct? What do I miss?

Comment: The sentence is poorly written. A more precise statement would have been that the elements of the empty set have any property. The meaning is the one in the theorem or, alternatively, that all quantified statements in the form $[(\forall x\in\emptyset_X) E(x)]$ are true. Obviously some properties are false when specialized to the empty set: namely, if we define $P(x)\equiv (\exists y\in x) y=y$, then $P(\emptyset_X)$ is false.

Comment: The empty set doesn't have the property of being nonempty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely *cannot* say that $f(\emptyset)=0$. It's just not true in general. For instance, let $f:\mathcal{P}(X)\to \mathbb{N}$ be the constant function $1$. Then $f(\emptyset)$ is equal to $1$ and certainly not $0$.

It is not true *at all* that the empty set has all properties. What is true is that any statement of the form $(\forall x\in X, E(x))$, where $E(x)$ is a statement, is true when $X=\emptyset$.

Comment: Statement: "All elephants in my pocket are red". It is true because there is not any elephant in my pocket. So the set of the elephants in this statement is empty. Now I say that this empty set (elephants in my pocket) has this property (they are red). But you say that it is not correct. You say that this *statement* is true but not the conclusion about this set. Do I understand you correct?

Comment: You are confusing two things. What you correctly understood is that for any property $P(x)$, $P(x)$ is true for any $x$ in $\emptyset$ (because there is no such $x$, so there cannot be a counter-example). But what you are saying ("the empty set has all properties") would mean that for any property $P(x)$, $P(\emptyset)$ is true. That is *completely* different, and absolutely false.

Comment: For instance, let $P(x)$ be the property "$1\in x$". Then $P(x)$ is true for all $x\in \emptyset$ (for trivial reasons), but clearly $P(\emptyset)$ is false (the empty set does not contain $1$). It is not the empty set that has all properties, it is its *elements* (because there are none).

Answer (score 1):

Well, consider $E(x)$ as a predicate in the free variable $x$.

If $X$ is the empty set, the implication $x\in X\Rightarrow E(x)$ is vacuously true as the premise ''$x\in X$'' is false and so the implication is true.